# Will the condition of a person become worse by COVID-19 if he is already suffering from a common cold/flu

Tags: covid-19, common-cold, coronavirus

Can the condition become worse, if a person has Normal flu and then he gets infected by coronavirus. Or if has just recovered from normal flu/cold and then gets infected by coronavirus